# Parsing array of multiple objects in Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

How to extract values present in array of multiple object's using jbuilder.?

i have an array of multiple objects.

```
@array1= [ ]
#pushed different types of objects into this array.
if xyz
@array1 << object_type1 # having fields id,f_name
else 
@array1 << object_type2 # having fields id,l_name
```

Now in jbuilder i want

```
json.array! @array1 do |myarray|
 json.id myarray.id
 json.name myarray.f_name || myarray.l_name # how to check object type here 
end
```

when i try this it is giving me error like

```
undefined method `l_name' for #<Object_type1:0xb496eda8>
```

How to check or tell jbuilder to which objecttype it has to use for name field.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your ObjectTypes are ActiveRecord models, you can do something a bit cleaner like:

```
json.array! @array1 do |myarray|
  json.name myarray.has_attribute? "f_name" ? myarray.f_name : myarray.l_name
  json.id myarray.id
end
```

This checks if `myarray` has an attribute of `f_name` and if it does uses that, otherwise we know it's the other `ObjectType` so we use `l_name`. If you haven't seen a one line if/else statement like this before, the syntax I'm using is:

```
<condition> ? <if_true> : <if_false>
```

So you can do things like:

```
@post.nil? ? return "No post here" : return "Found a post"
```

Or you can add a method to each of your ObjectTypes in their models like:

```
def name
  l_name # or f_name, depending on which ObjectType it is
end
```

Then you could do:

```
json.array! @array1 do |myarray|
  json.name myarray.name
  json.id myarray.id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether it is a correct way or not but i tried and got what i wanted

```
 json.array! @array1 do |myaarray|
     if myarray.class == ObjectType
       json.name myarray.f_name
       json.id myarray.id
      else
       json.name myarray.l_name
       json.id myarray.id
      end  
   end
```